# Can we rename 'builds' to 'versions'?

Tags: discussion, tags

A while ago I [suggested](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/272/599) a [versions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/versions) tag. The idea seemed to be agreed with, but it was decided to merge it with the existing [builds](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/builds) tag.

I agree that the tags overlap to the point of being the same thing and should be one tag, however I think [versions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/versions) would be a better name, simply because [builds](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/builds) seems like less widely used terminology when referring to pre-compiled distributed software, and [questions about actually building blender are considered off-topic here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/400/599).

Should this be changed?
*And if so, how can it be changed? Will we need a moderator to do some magic?*

Comment: You have my vote.

Comment: @DantheMan Since it seems no one objects, do you know how to do the actual renaming? Do you have some mod power or do we have to create a new tag and then synonymize it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm definitely in full support of this tag change.
How will we define *Versions*? What will the tag be used for?

Comment: How about "Use this tag for questions involving specific versions of blender"?

Comment: Make it sound legal "Past and present".

Comment: The tag has been renamed.

Comment: I've edited the tag wiki now, hopefully everyone agrees with it.

Answer (score 1):

I support this move. The only issue would be if there are "official" builds (like say, a feature branch) that we allow questions for (do we?) - as these might not be best tagged with [version](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version).